# How to manage Cron Jobs in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cron

Is there any node.js library that allows you to create n number of cron jobs providing some sort of key and then having the possibility to remove/edit a particular job by key?

For example, I'm looking for something like this:

```
import cronManagerLibrary from 'library';

export const startJob = (key) => {
  cronManagerLibrary.addJob(key, '10 * * * * *', function);
}

export const removeJob = (key) => {
  cronManagerLibrary.removeJob(key);
}

export const updateJob = (key) => {
  cronManagerLibrary.updateJob(key, interval);
}

export const listJobs = () => {
  cronManagerLibrary.list();
}
```

---

UPDATE:

I've found this library [cron-job-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-job-manager) that does exactly what I need, but I'm not sure how to persist the list of jobs since I need to create a job manager object every time...

This is what I've tried:

```
import CronJobManager from 'cron-job-manager';

export startJob = (key) => {
  const manager = new CronJobManager();
  taskFunction = () => {
    console.log('CRON JOB RUNNING');
  }
  manager.add(key,'10 * * * * *', taskFunction);
  manager.start(key);
  console.log(manager);
}
```

Every time I call the `startJob` function in order to create a new cron job the `manager` object will not keep the previous started job... is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Do u want to do this on a linux os or any other os?

Comment: I need it to run on a Linux OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) module to do this. Install cron using `npm i cron`. As an example,

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

new CronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
    console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

See documentation for more info,

If you want to do more cron activities you can always use any terminal commands. See below example,

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("crontab -l", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: There is nothing specified in the documentation about how you can get the list of the running jobs ... do you have any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do u have any experience in linux bash terminal. You have right?

Comment: Yes, but I need to retrieve the active jobs using node. I think that `crontab` helps with that.

Comment: Listing jobs doesn't seem to be working ... it returns 'no crontab for [user] even if there are running jobs

Comment: This should be same as running on your terminal, so cannot be. Try running that command on your terminal and see

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, to manage your cron jobs!

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

export class CronManager {
    constructor() {
        this._jobs = {};
    }
    add(name, periodText, fn) {
        this._jobs[name] = {
            name,
            cron: new CronJob(periodText, fn, null, true)
        };
    }
    stop(name) {
        delete this._jobs[name];
    }
    delete(name) {
        delete this._jobs[name];
    }
    stopAll() {
        for (let cron in this._jobs) {
            let activeCron = this._jobs[cron].cron.running;
            if (activeCron.running) {
                activeCron.stop();
            }
        }
    }
    list() {
        return this._jobs;
    }
    running(name) {
        return this._jobs[name].cron.running;
    }
    lastDate(name) {
        return this._jobs[name].cron.lastDate();
    }
    nextDates(name) {
        return this._jobs[name].cron.nextDates();
    }
}
```